# Prevent to change url address bar manually. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, web

I m trying to prevent manipulation of websites.In which user try to manipulate sites by changing url address bar manually

Comment: Please could you expand on your question. Perhaps give an actual example as it is unclear what is required.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can use long, random-looking, unguessable URLs

You can't stop them changing the URL address, but you can make it difficult for them to find the right URL to do you harm.